# Is it possible to set a video cover for a page via the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We're currently managing the covers of our clients Facebook pages through the API, which works fine:

We POST a picture to `/{pageid}/photos`, get the id of the photo, and then POST to `/{pageid}` with the photo id as the `cover` parameter, as is hinted in the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) which says cover should be a numeric string or an integer and is used to Update the cover field.

However, if I try to do the same by uploading a video and passing the id of the video, I get this error from the facebook sdk :

```
(#2) Service temporarily unavailable
```

And this happens every time I try on different days so it's not like it's really a temporary issue on their end.

Is there a way to post a video cover via the API ? Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Th `cover` field is of type CoverPhoto, so no surprise that doesn’t allow for videos. Documentation doesn’t mention cover videos at all, so I would assume that’s currently not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I checked it as well and found it impossible to set a video cover.

are you still able to manage covers as photos?
I was able to until very recently but now I am getting "Unsupported post request." (even when trying in the Graph API explorer)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing now, when I first posted about video covers the photo covers were still working fine, but now I'm getting the same response as you, "Unsupported post request".

Comment: Note that not only that the API is no longer working, the current cover photo is removed but the new cover photo is not updated. 
so if you are providing such a service to your customers you may actually cause damage to them.

Answer (score 0):

Nicolus, there is an open bug for the cover update issue:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/517172448680007